# How to implement identity providers in Azure websites?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

Is there a way to easily implement identity providers (Google, Facebook, etc) for an Azure website that is hosting a web api that will be accessed from HTML and mobile clients?

In Azure Mobile Services, identity providers are easy to configure and use.  Can any of this built-in functionality be leveraged for Azure websites?  If not, are there any good resources on how to best implement identity providers for Azure websites/web api?

Answer (score 1):

For your web site you can in Visual Studio 2012 use the Identity and Access Tool, which will help you set up security. If you want the Identiy Providers you mention, you might want to look into ACS.

Though, your Web API cant relly be secured by any of those IP's. The web api is not really your frontend, right? I think you should look into Oauth 2.0 for the web api's.

One other related idea is to look into Owin: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e21bf653-dfe1-4d81-b3d3-795cb104066e

So, each client (html, mobile client, etc) will have to authorize the user on its own. For example via Google or Facebook (perhaps with the help of ACS). Then, each client will use Oauth, without interaction of its user, to authorize against the web api. 2 different authorization methods, ok?

To my knowledge you can not leverage the Mobile Services authorization functionality into the Azure Websites.

Peter